# provide multiple forms on one templates with multiple instances of the form in django getting trouble

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, formset

I have three classes
class a
class b
class c

Class b has Foreign key to class a and class c has foreign key to class b. I am able to get all three forms in templates but i am not able to create the multiple instances of form c. Because b can be associated with the multiple c's. So for the form c i want one button add more there so it can create the multiple forms there. And once i get the multiple forms i need to save that to the database for appropriate table. What is the the right way to proceed for this.

Guide me for this Thank you.

Comment: May be you should use `inline_formset` of `C` in the `B` form. And send ajax response to the `B` form when save your `A` form (to set fk field to `A`).

Comment: Any links or hint for the same?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example

Comment: Or better don't send response to `B` - just save `A` and set it to b_modelform_class init with request.POST, then save `B` and `C` formset.

Comment: CFormSet = inlineformset_factory(B, C,
    form=maybe_some_modelform_class_to_C,
    extra=1
)